# Executing create table faster in MySQL with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm developing an app that creates tables from script in MySQL with JDBC.

That process take about 20 minutes and create 640 tables with primary and foreign keys (without data).

This is the code that create a tables

```
st=conexion.createStatement();
for(StringBuilder sentencia:sentencias){
    try{
         st.executeUpdate(sentencia.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            errores.add(sentencia);
        }
  }
```

Can someone please help me to optimize the code? I'm using isolation level transaction and threads.

Comment: We (maybe) help fix broken code. We're not here to optimize your code for you.

Comment: I want to know if exist a technique that can  be this process more quickly. I understand your answer @MarcB

Comment: Don't use isolation level. Nothing is inserting data. You're creating empty tables.

Comment: You don't tell us what your mysql settings are nor what you machine is doing during the 20 minutes. Which process (java or mysql) is using CPU? Are you I/O bound or CPU bound? This is most likely a question of tuning mysql parameters than optimizing java code.

Comment: Why not run a script. I can't see it taking more than 3 minutes max. Even if that means you dynamically write the .sql. Then just run it.

Comment: Thanks @Rob,  I was thinking that the problem was in my java code but i execute the same script directly en database and the time was the same.